# create sequence diagram generator ruby gem

Tags: ruby, uml

So I want to create a gem similar to VCR that starts recording method calls
along with the classes those methods are in, maybe even line number, and stop recording and generate say a yml file or something which is effectively a UML sequence diagram metadata description of the run.

Extending that even further, I want to use the mermaid gem to actually spit out a picture UML diagram.

I'm thinking of taking the approach outlined in this reddit post, basically storing a array of hashes to parse into some kind of Plant text downstream.
https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/11ns2l/does_a_uml_sequence_diagram_generation_gem_exist/

http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/ospace.html#tracingyourprogramsexecution

Anyways, finally, my question is... Is there a better way to approach this?
Or should I just kind of follow the idea proposed in the reddit?

Comment: The answer you already have is essentially what I'd suggest starting with. There is also an [Object-Oriented API](http://ruby-doc.org/core/TracePoint.html) in the standard library that wraps this Kernel method, which you could use.

Comment: Just for fun recently, I actually [wrote my own version](https://github.com/tom-lord/search_warrant) of a method tracer. You *could* use that/a variation of it, but the standard library approach is possibly a better approach; particularly since it also handles C methods.

Answer (score 3):

A simplest solution would be to generate a plant uml file. A Plant file is far simpler than an XMI file and Plant is integrated in a lot's of tool.

It could be an alternative.

[plantUML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlantUML)

For example:

```
@startuml
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
Alice -> Bob: Another authentication Request
Alice <-- Bob: another authentication Response
@enduml
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[ZemUML](https://www.zenuml.com) support C-like code.

For example,`ZenUML.isAwesome()`will generate the following diagram:

[image]

If your meta DSL follows the same syntax, it can be directly integrated with ZenUML. The JS library is published as npm module.