# Which patterns, practices or standards exist to store whole Diagram (or Models)?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, uml, object-oriented-analysis

We are developing a **simple Modeling Tools** (to use it in other refactoring tools) to manage diagrams like CDG (Call Dependency Graph between classes) and etc.

Our diagrams are **similar to UML diagrams** and they have some details like Use Case or Class Diagram's details.

In this project we should store diagrams and open them later for some changes by users. (Similar to other modeling tools)

Basic Implementation of this tools in Java are here: 
https://github.com/AsenaTechAcademy/Irani-OOP-in-Java-gModeler

**The Question is**: Which patterns or practices exist to store a diagram? Which standards exist to do this (and our team should learn them)?

Two factors are important to out project:

1. performance of reading and writing diagrams.
2. diagram size on the hard/server.

Comment: GraphViz DOT language will give you auto-layout of dependency graphs, if you can generate the DSL (domain specific language) DOT. I looked at your [PDF](https://github.com/AsenaTechAcademy/Irani-OOP-in-Java-gModeler/blob/master/Class%20Diagram/gModeler001-Class-Diagram.pdf) and it has a lot of detail. I think no tool can make complex diagrams look "readable". The "important" information depends on some context. That said, I like PlantUML, as its language is also based on GraphViz and I've "instrumented" my modeling tools to generate it. You can't go the other way, however.

Comment: Thanks a lot. GraphViz DOT is very nice representation. However it has some limitations in our project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this is the best, but UML define two XML formats for UML schemas:

- XMI which stores the UML element [XMI](http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/About-XMI/)
- UML DI which stores the diagram [UMLDI](http://www.omg.org/spec/UMLDI/About-UMLDI/)

"All tools" allow to export schema in XMI and UMLDI.

In Eclipse environment, the UML2 project allows to manage XMI file (and maybe umldi) [UML2 tools](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2)

A classical solution to store schema is also SVG : [SVG](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp)

Another simple but less smart is plant uml, see [plant uml question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517259/create-sequence-diagram-generator-ruby-gem)

Comment: Thanks a lot, very nice answer and good collection of technologies. I'm just waiting (not accepting) for new or best solutions.

Comment: @g.Irani  no problem, it is an interesting topic. You saw that as answer to "plant uml question" someone proposed another solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out the [Eclipse Modeling Framework](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/). Lots of tools in this area use [Ecore](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.9.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/package-summary.html) to store the models. The advantage of this is that its easier to exchange the models between different tools. Some UML tools allow for exporting as XMI but then its not always possible to import this into another tool even though this might support importing XMI. The reason for this is that there might be small differences in the way they use the XMI file. I would definitely check this out. One other advantage of this is that there are lots of tools in the EMF/Ecore universe, e.g. to compare different versions of a model (e.g. [EMF Compare](https://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/)).